# Access to the nested object's fields

Tags: javascript

I want to create function to toggle field value at any level of nested object

```js
function toggle(object, field) {
  object[field] = !object[field];
}
```

But if I want to change nested objects like this:

```
outer: {
  inner: {
    enable: true
  }
}
```

I can't pass it just like `toggle(outer, 'inner.price')` or `toggle(outer.inner, 'price')`. Is there some trick with computed properties that allow me not to parse parameter string and dig inside object recursively?

Comment: Recursion loop is what you need.

Comment: Uh, `toggle(outer.inner, 'price')` actually should work

Comment: "*Is there some trick with computed properties?*" No. You need to dig inside the object one way or the other.

Comment: @Bergi it works but i want to run it like 
`toggle_my_obj('field_on_the_first_lvl')` and `toggle_my_obj('field_on_the_second_lvl')` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS you can actually get to properties by using their names and `outer['inner']` is the same as `outer.inner` but you don't need to know the property name at "compile" time.

You should be able to get away with splitting a string such as `outer.inner.enable` to find the property you want with recursion.

```js
let myObject = {
  outer: {
    inner: {
      enable: true
    }
  }
};

const toggle = (object, path) => {
  // get the name of the next property
  let [prop, ...subProps] = path.split('.');
  
  // check if the property to toggle is at this object
  if (subProps.length == 0) {
    // toggle said propertty
    object[prop] = !object[prop];
  } else {
    // toggle property in child object
    toggle(object[prop], subProps.join('.'));
  }
}

console.log(myObject.outer.inner.enable); // true

toggle(myObject, 'outer.inner.enable');

console.log(myObject.outer.inner.enable); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

> Nothing beats Lodash in this regards

```js
function toggle(obj, prop) {
  _.set(obj, prop, !_.get(obj, prop));
}

var obj = {
  outer: {
    inner: {
      enable: true
    }
  }
};

toggle(obj, ["outer", "inner", "enable"]);

console.log(obj);

toggle(obj, ["outer", "inner", "enable"]);

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

> Explanation:

1. Lodash is a must have tool-set in your JavaScript arsenal
2. _.get() gets a property from deep within an object like so: _.get(obj, ["outer", "inner", "enable"])
3. _.set() sets a property deep within an object

Checkout the respective documentations: [GET](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get) & [SET](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#set)

Answer (score 0):

Create a recursive function

```js
var outer = {
  inner: {
    innerTwo: {
      enable: true
    }
  }
}

function toggle(obj, keyName) {
  for (var keys in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(keys) && typeof obj[keys] === 'object') {
      if (obj[keys][keyName] !== undefined) {
        obj[keys][keyName] = !obj[keys][keyName]
      } else {
        toggle(obj[keys], keyName)
      }
    }
  }
}
toggle(outer, 'enable');
console.log(outer)
```

Comment: What you offer gonna run over all object keys, which in not performance-effective.